# Protect Sub-Div Background

Tags: html, css

I've a div (inside a div) that i want to keep its background unchanged when i change upper-div's background.

Is there a way to preserve child div's background property?

P.S: I can't change child div's background to its old value manually. That's because it has

```
td.name:before {
    clip: rect(0px, 490px, 20px, 0px);
    white-space: nowrap;
    content:
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

inside and when i change the page's background i lose the "content".

Comment: how do you "change" the background? JQuery? or CSS (:hover, etc) ?

Comment: By CSS, btw solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Child div's stack order was causing the problem. Changed the "z-index" value and it's done.

Answer (score 2):

Your child's background, if explicitly set, won't be affected by its parent's background. In the example below you can see that we explicitly set a background rule for both elements. As such, the parent background will not affect the child's background.

This wasn't the case with the color property. Because we set it for the parent, and not the child, the child inherits its color from the parent.

```
<style>
  #parent {
    background: red;
    color: white;
  }
  #child {
    background: green;
  }
</style>
<div id="parent">
  <p>I am white text</p>
  <div id="child">
    <p>I am also white text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/emajit/edit#html,live

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration, appreciated.